# Time format in Inlfux Db using curl

Tags: database, influxdb, time-format

when I query my Influx database using "curl" I get a result with time in a format like this: "2017-02-07T15:29:46.393796063Z".
I need nanoseconds instead, as shown in Influx itself when I make queries.
How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
Just using flag `--data-urlencode epoch="n"` in curl request.
Where `n` is nanoseconds.